# How to create a new incremental reference number in the next row in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have inherited an Excel register which has the following VBA module.  It is supposed to create a new reference based on the one in the row above and also copy the formatting down.  In reality all it does is copy exactly what is in the row above.

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & lr).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & lr).Resize(2)

Rows(lr).Offset(0, 0).Copy
Rows(lr).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I am new to VBA and I don't recognise any of this, can anyone tell me what it is trying to do or how I change it to what I need.

Comment: What's in the row above - can you give us a sample reference number?

Comment: MOC0001 so the next would be MOC0002 and so on

Answer (score 1):

Let's try and break this down:

```
Rows
```

returns a collection of `Range` objects on the active worksheet; each `Range` object represents a single row.

```
Rows.Count
```

returns the number of possible rows on a worksheet. This number depends on which version of Excel you are using; in my case it is `1048576`.

```
"A" & Rows.Count
```

returns the address of the last cell in column A, or `A1048576`

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count)
```

returns a `Range` object representing the last cell in column A.

Calling the `End` method:

```
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
```

returns a new `Range` object whose end has been moved up from the end of the previous range. In other words, the new `Range` object represents the last used cell in column A.

Finally, we want to get the row number of the last used cell, using the `Row` property; and we'll store this number in the `lr` variable.

```
lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

---

Let's look at the next line:

```
Range("A" & lr)
```

returns a `Range` object representing the cell at column A and the row number at `lr`, or the last used cell in column A.

We want to call the `AutoFill` method, to fill the values from a previous set of cells into a new set of cells. In this case, we want to auto-fill from the cell in the previous row to the cell in the next row. We can do that by passing a `Range` object representing the last used cell together with the new cell into the `Destination` parameter.

We can get such a `Range` by using the `Resize` method, passing in `2` as the number of rows in the new `Range`:

```
Range("A" & lr).Resize(2)
```

And calling the `AutoFill` method:

```
Range("A" & lr).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & lr).Resize(2)
```

---

But note that there are different ways to auto-fill: we could auto-fill the same values as in the previous cells. In order to specify that we want to treat the previous values as a series to generate new values, we need to pass in the autofill type:

```
Range("A" & lr).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & lr).Resize(2), Type:=xlFillSeries
```

---

**VBA references**

- [`&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator)

**Excel object model references**

Note that **Rows** and **Range** are members of the undocumented **Global** object, but they appear to work the same way as the corresponding properties on the **Range** object.

- [**Range** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))
- [**Rows**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.rows) and [**Count**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.count) properties
- [**Range**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.range) and [**End**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end) properties
- [**XlDirection.xlUp** enumeration constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldirection)
- [**Row** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row)
- [**Resize** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)
- [**AutoFill** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill)
- [**XlAutoFillType.xlFillSeries** enumeration constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlautofilltype)

Comment: I see you decided to tackle the "Can anyone tell me what it is trying to do?" :-)

Comment: @BigBen Have I succeeded? Also, I benefit, because I always get confused on how to use the **Range** property. Now I know.

Comment: "Have I succeeded?" A resounding yes.

Answer (score 0):

A guess, but I would specify the `Type` parameter of [`Range.AutoFill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill):

```
Range("A" & lr).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & lr).Resize(2), Type:=xlFillSeries
```